# How do I get and/or set the parameters of a predicated CriteriaQuery?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to refactor my Spring Specifications (org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification) in order to use JSR 310 classes. In other words my specifications use Date and I want to use Instant.

In order to do this I wanted to create unit tests for the specifications. My idea was to get the resulting query string and compare them before and after the refactoring.

If there are the same as after the refactoring then everything should be good.

However the parameters of my query are always empty. If I try and set them I get an IllegalArgumentExcpeption.

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    Specification<Sp> sp = SpSpecification.betweenDates(now, now);

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManagerFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Sp> q = cb.createQuery(Sp.class);
    Root<Sp> root = q.from(Sp.class);

    Predicate p = sp.toPredicate(root, q, cb);
    q.where(p);

    TypedQuery<Sp> typedQuery = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().createQuery(q);

    List<Sp> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();

    // doesn't show the parameter values
    String queryString = typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
    // always empty
    System.out.println(typedQuery.getParameters());
    // ok get named parameters --> [param5, param0, param3, param4, param1, param2]
    String[] namedParameters = typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getNamedParameters();
    // try and set one of them -> IllegalArgumentException (Unable to locate parameter registered with that name)
    typedQuery.setParameter("param5", now);
```

Comment: what parameters? Your JPA Criteria code adds no parameters, and you don't set the values of any parameters before executing it. But then you could easily call `typedQuery.getParameters()` if you are convinced there are some. And FYI there is no such thing as a "JPA Specification"; there is a Spring Specification, but that's nothing to do with the JPA API

Comment: Good point. I thought of that as well and tried to set a named parameter and I got an IllegalArgumentException. I added this to my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `query.getNamedParameters()`
with `query.getParameterValue(namedParameter)` to get the values.
Since I can not find a way to use spring data `specification` to do a join query on `unrelated entities`, that is not defined by one-to-one or one-to-many relations , I use following code to combine specifications(which in this case  play as a "fields where assembler" to convert form fields to a where clause)

```java
@Override
    public Page<TestData> find(Specification<TestData> testDataSpecification,
                               Specification patientSpecification,
                               Pageable page) {
        String basicQuerystring = " from TestData t , Patient p  ";
        StringBuffer finalQs = new StringBuffer();
        finalQs.append(basicQuerystring);
        String testDataAlias = "t";
        Query testDataQuery = toQuery(testDataSpecification, TestData.class, testDataAlias);
        String patientAlias = "p";
        Query patientQuery = toQuery(patientSpecification, Patient.class, patientAlias);

        String testDataWhere = getWhereQs(testDataQuery, testDataAlias);
        String patientWhere = getWhereQs(patientQuery, patientAlias);

        StringBuffer allWhere = new StringBuffer(" where t.patientCode=p.hospitalCode ");
        allWhere.append(testDataWhere.length() > 0 ? (" and " + testDataWhere) : "");
        allWhere.append(patientWhere.length() > 0 ? (" and " + patientWhere) : "");

        finalQs.append(allWhere);

        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new HashMap();

        // page and sort
        int pageSize = page.getPageSize();
        long offset = page.getOffset();
        String sortString = page.getSort().toString();
        String countString = "select  count(*) " + finalQs.toString();
        if (!"UNSORTED".equals(sortString)) {
            finalQs.append(" sort by " + sortString);
        }
        javax.persistence.Query finalQuery = entityManager.createQuery(finalQs.toString());
        finalQuery.setFirstResult((int) offset);
        finalQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);

        // add params
        if (testDataQuery != null) {
            addParamValue(testDataAlias, testDataQuery, paramMap);
        }
        if (patientQuery != null) {
            addParamValue(patientAlias, patientQuery, paramMap);
        }
        addAllParamsToQuery(paramMap, finalQuery);

        List resultList = finalQuery.getResultList();
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(resultList, page, new LongSupplier() {
            @Override
            public long getAsLong() {
                javax.persistence.Query countQuery = entityManager.createQuery(countString);
                addAllParamsToQuery(paramMap, countQuery);
                return (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult();
            }
        });
    }

private Query toQuery(Specification specification, Class aClass, String classAlias) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery query = cb.createQuery(aClass);
        Root<TestData> root = query.from(aClass);
        root.alias(classAlias);
        Predicate predicate = specification.toPredicate(root, query, cb);
        return predicate == null ? null : entityManager.createQuery(query.where(predicate)).unwrap(Query.class);
    }

private String getWhereQs(Query query, String entityAlias) {
        if (query == null)
            return "";
        String queryString = query.getQueryString();
        int containsWhere = queryString.indexOf("where");
        String substring = "";
        if (containsWhere != -1) {
            substring = queryString.substring(containsWhere + "where".length());
        }
        return substring.replaceAll(":param", ":" + entityAlias + "param");
    }

private void addParamValue(String testDataAlias, Query testDataQuery, Map<String, Object> paramMap) {
        for (String namedParameter : testDataQuery.getNamedParameters()) {
            paramMap.put(testDataAlias + namedParameter, testDataQuery.getParameterValue(namedParameter));
        }
    }

private void addAllParamsToQuery(Map<String, Object> paramMap, javax.persistence.Query finalQuery) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> each : paramMap.entrySet()) {
            String paramName = each.getKey();
            Object paramValue = each.getValue();
            finalQuery.setParameter(paramName, paramValue);
        }
    }
```